# Fixing a view on an Image Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have an image that is using Auto-Layout constraints. The image is a blackboard. I want to fix a view to fill the blackboard, so I can put some labels in there, as if it had some written things in the blackboard. I tried to use constraints in this view, but never fills the blackboard. How can I do this?. I uploaded an image to be more specific. Thanks!

[image]

P.S.: I colored the View.

Comment: What's the contentMode of your background image or its layout constraints? It has to respect the same.

Comment: The contentMode is Scale to Fill and I am using constraints.